# Python print/write

Tags: python, printing

Ok so, when I print text and text1 it displays something like this:

```
END OF TEXT HERE BEGINNING OF TEXT1 HERE
```

I want the output to be like this for both print and write:

```
END OF TEXT HERE
BEGINNING OF TEXT1 HERE
```

I want the output to be like this for both print and write:

```
END OF TEXT HERE
BEGINNING OF TEXT1 HERE
```

I tried split(), but I think I'm doing it in the wrong area..Thanks for the help.

My Code is below:

```
print(text, text1)

with open("text.txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(text + text1)
```

Comment: To help us avoid making assumptions about your problem, you should make a habit of providing a _complete_ [mre]. In this case, including the definitions of `text` and `text1` would make your MRE complete, although it would be a pretty safe assumption that `text = "END OF TEXT HERE"` and `text1 = "BEGINNING OF TEXT1 HERE"`. Please also read [ask] for general advice, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Why you cant edit it?

Comment: You _can_ edit your post by clicking on the edit link just under the [tag:python] tag to the left of your (and my) name (or this link -> [edit])

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the values of `text` and `text1`

```py
text="END OF TEXT HERE"
text1="BEGINNING OF TEXT1 HERE"
print(text + "\n" + text1)

with open("text.txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(text + "\n" + text1)
```

- `\n` is escape sequence and represents a newline character, used to insert a line break or can say start a new line.
- When `\n` escape sequence is encountered within a string, it tells Python to move the cursor to the beginning of the next line.

Comment: In addition to giving the solution, a great answer would also explain _why_ this happens, why the solution works, and provide links to relevant documentation and/or additional reading. It might be pretty obvious to you or an experienced programmer, but probably not so to OP and future beginner readers. See [answer].

Comment: Thank you Sauron! Also sorry for any misunderstanding Pranav Hosangadi.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this requirement, you need to use the newline character '\n'.

```
print("Hello world")
```

prints

```
Hello world!
```

Whereas

```
print("Hello\nworld")
```

prints

```
Hello
world!
```

The newline character is interpreted as a line break in Python and multiple other languages.

Now to get back to the original question, we need to first declare the strings

```
text = "END OF TEXT HERE"
text1 = "BEGINNING OF TEXT1 HERE"
```

Notice that neither of the stings contain the newlne character.

Now to print the strings on the console, we need to modify the print statement in this way :

```
print(text,text1,sep="\n")
```

The last argument 'sep' specifies the separator which should come in between text and text1. We have specified '\n', hence the output will be :

```
END OF TEXT HERE
BEGINNING OF TEXT1 HERE
```

To achieve the same effect in the file, we will have to modify the write method call as follows :

```
file.write(text + "\n" + text1)
```

Here '\n' is placed in between the text and text1 variables. On execution when the composite string is written to the file, '\n' causes a newline to be introduced in the file.

Also, you should always close a file once you don't need it anymore.

```
file.close()
```

Here's the full script :

```
text = "END OF TEXT HERE"
text1 = "BEGINNING OF TEXT1 HERE"

print(text,text1,sep="\n")

with open("text.txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(text + "\n" + text1)

file.close()
```